# What is the simplest Event design pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Lately, I've been pondering about the following problem for a while. For the code bellow, what is the easiest way to modify `Game::counter` via `Event::Perform()` method which is called from Game class?
I considered Observer and Command design patterns, but it seems that there is a much simpler way to do this.

```
class Game
{
public:
    Game();
private:
    int counter;
    vector<Event*> Events;
};

class Event
{
public:
    virtual void Perform() = 0;
};
```

Thank you

Comment: `std::function` `std::forward`https://juanchopanzacpp.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/simple-observer-pattern-implementation-c11/

Comment: @Ðаn I was considering this variant. However, this solution seemed to be a bit sophisticated for this kind of problem.

Comment: @VIRUS What on earth is _sophisticated_ about `std::function`?

Comment: @VIRUS from my point of view, it's far more easier to use `std::function` than to implement an abstract class or interface to every class that want to be aware of an event. You do it once, inside your `Game` class and boom you're done. You only need to use `std::bind` after, no need to implement an interface and the additional overhead

Answer (score 1):

Directly from `Perform`, none. `counter` is private, so it can only be accessed by `Game`, as part of one of the functions of the interface it provides.

Calling this function is then just a matter of having access to the right `Game` instance. You can pass that one as a parameter to `Perform`:

```
virtual void Perform(Game &) = 0;
```

... or inject it into derived `Event`s:

```
struct MyEvent : Event {
    MyEvent(Game &game) : _game{&game} { }

    void Perform() const override {
        // Do something with *game
    }

private:
    Game *_game;
};
```

Since I guess we are talking about the `Event`s referenced by `Game::Events`, which `Game` itself will process, the parameter looks like the most cohesive approach.

Comment: I was just about to implement it this way, actually. The problem is that I do now know which way is better for my specific case.

Btw, whonever downvoted this answer, please explain why.

Comment: @VIRUS I think the first one is more logical, if I understood your model correctly. I added a bit of rationale to the answer.